# How to configure Intellisense for electron (A nodejs library)?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, electron

How do I configure Visual Studio 2015 Community edition to recognize parts of the Electron API. For example electron has electron.app() which is used as an event emitter. How do I get Intellisense to recognize functions like these which are defined in a nodejs module (Handled by NPM.)

Happy to provide more details if I missed something or if I wasn't clear, Zac.

Comment: I would know it too. Or maybe how to configure some other IDE. I tried also VS Code, Atom.io and WebStorm. I didn't see suggestions from electron module. They suggest just what I already typed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for Visual Studio, but in VS code this should do the trick:

```
typings install github-electron --source dt --global
```

I didn't try that myself, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372358/electron-js-intellisense-and-vscode) it says that it works. (Yeah, I know that the question is pretty old).