# Intellisense in VSCode for electron app development

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, electron

I am developing windows desktop app using Electron and VSCode. I do not see any intellisence when I try to use functions from electron. My query is,
how to configure vscode to enable the electron intellisense? In general I want to know what procedures I need to follow so that I can get intellisense feature in JavaScript code.

Comment: Just use typescript. Although it's possible to use definition files in js

Answer (score 2):

Running this should do the trick

```
typings install github-electron --source dt --global
```

### Update

The new method would be to install the @types through npm via:

`npm i -D @types/electron`

Looking at that repository though, it says that if you have the following included in your dependencies you'll get typings.

https://github.com/electron/electron

### Update 2

Sounds like you'll get types from the electron dependency now itself. It took less than a year to have 3 different ways of doing this. Nobody will probably ever see this now as it should not be an issue with modern packages and IDEs.

Comment: Yes and also you could install the VsCode Extension: ext install typings-autoinstaller

Comment: `Unable to find  "github-electron" ("dt") in the registry`. Can you help me with this message ? This is what I get after executing the command.

Comment: @TomaTomov You should be running `npm i -D @types/electron` now instead.

Comment: now `@types/electron` is deprecated. `"electron provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/electron installed!"`